# Unicode character in octets to hexadecimal

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Unicode character in octets is something like 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx. How can I transform these octets in hexadecimal notation like U+XXXX?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `iconv`'s UTF-8 decoder to avoid having to write one yourself:

```
function utf8_to_codepoints($s) {
    return unpack('V*', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $s));
}

$data= "Caf\xc3\xa9 \xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac \xf0\x9d\x84\x9e"; // Café 日本 
var_export(utf8_to_codepoints($data));
```

gives:

```
array (
  1 => 67,
  2 => 97,
  3 => 102,
  4 => 233,
  5 => 32,
  6 => 26085,
  7 => 26412,
  8 => 32,
  9 => 119070,
)
```

which can be converted to U+nnnn format using `dechex`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's the [document that definitively defines UTF-8 encoding](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3629.html).

The two octets in your example: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx encode one Unicode character.  Its binary code is - well, just take those x's (bits) and put them together.  You'll get a number - in binary, but you can convert it to decimal or hexadecimal if you want.  That's the same number as XXXX in U+XXXX.

How did I know that 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx encode one character?  There may be three kinds of octets in a UTF-8 stream:

- 10xxxxxx - trailing octets
- 0xxxxxxx - ASCII characters
- 110xxxxx, 1110xxxx, etc. - leading octets in the sequence.

Sequences of leading and trailing octets are used to encode Unicode points from 128 and up.  110xxxxx means it starts a sequence of two octets, 1110xxxx starts a sequence of three octets, etc.  This way you can isolate sequences from each other.  Then take x's from the all octets in the sequence and that's your Unicode code point.